# problem creating an intent-filter to launch my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want to launch my own settings app when entering in "Wi-Fi Settings" (Settings/Wireless Settings). Checking the AndroidManifest.xml of the Settings app in the android source code...the intent filter created for that WifiSettings activity is this:

```
<activity android:name=".wifi.WifiSettings"
                android:label="@string/wifi_settings"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE_LAUNCH" />
                <category android:name="com.android.settings.SHORTCUT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For my own app, the intent-filter that I created is this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyWifiSettings"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For some reason this does not work. I'm missing something and I don't know what. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try changing the string "android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS" to something that doesn't begin with 'android' (because if you are a non-platform app, you might not be allowed to use the 'android' prefix).  Try changing it to 'com.foo.WIFI_SETTINGS' and then launch the activity using 'com.foo.WIFI_SETTINGS' just to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, settings app is launched via particular component name (Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }). So you can't replace it with your own.