# Launch Activity with Intent Filter on Right Time

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-intent, android-manifest

I want to launch my own media player application when I want to watch a video from Youtube. When I write `android:scheme="http"` and `android:host="m.youtube.com"` it is OK. But, it asks everywhere in m.youtube.com to open my app. So, it gets annoying. I tried to use pathPattern, pathPrefix and path to solve this but I didn't get ahead. All I want is clearly this:

- When the link is like `"http://m.youtube.com/index?desktop_uri=%2F%gl=US#"` the intent filter shouldn't launch my app.
- When the link is like `"http://m.youtube.com/index?desktop_uri=%2F&gl=US#/watch?xl=xl_blazer&v=k3Cdqx1qFX8"` my application should be launched.

Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: You don't mention which `pathPattern` and `pathPrefix` values you've tried.

Comment: I've tried so many. It only gets /index as path. Question mark is the main problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can have a look at this link:
[problem creating an intent-filter to launch my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457757/problem-creating-an-intent-filter-to-launch-my-app)
Also, you can try data element attribute and action element in intenet.some thing like this
, though I have not tried.

This link explains more about this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html